# PHP multiple file upload, remove empty uploads from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have made a function to work with sinlge file uploads and multiple file uploads to the effect that when multiple file uploads are detected PHP's default array setup is not used and a more manageable array is made.

Multiple Files HTML:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="userFile[]" class="userFile">
        <input type="file" name="userFile[]" class="userFile">
        <input type="file" name="userFile[]" class="userFile">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

Alternate Single Files HTML:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="userFile" class="userFile">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
function checkUploadedFile()
{
    $file;
    $files;
    $file_arr_keys;

    foreach($_FILES as $element) {

        if (is_array($element['name'])) {

            $file_count = count($element['name']);
            $file_arr_keys = array_keys($element);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++) {
                foreach ($file_arr_keys as $key) {
                    $files[$i][$key] = $element[$key][$i];
                }
            }

        } else {
            $file = $element;
        }
    }

    if (isset($file)) return $file;
    return $files;

}
```

Would create something like this if the multiple files form were used and only one file were uploaded:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => IMG_0015.JPG
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpMEaSSc
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 5191142
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Problem: How can I change the above output array so that it only has one element if the other file elements are empty? As in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => IMG_0015.JPG
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpMEaSSc
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 5191142
        )
)
```

Comment: Check `error` field.

Answer (score 2):

Just filter your array through [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-filter.php) function

```
$filtered = array_filter($files, function($file){
    return $file['error'] === 0; 
});
```

Got it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, by comparing your array, it would seem there are distinct values for each empty file. You could use any of them.

Iterate over your $files array and if any of the bools are met size,error,name, and/or type are empty or 0, use the unset() function to remove it from the array by it's key.

EG

```
foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    if ($file['size'] == 0) {
        unset($files[$key]);
    }
}
```

Or you could adapt this logic into your above function and never set it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore empty file in the loop.
Change your php file as:

```
function checkUploadedFile()
{
    $file;
    $files;
    $file_arr_keys;

    foreach($_FILES as $element) {

        if (is_array($element['name'])) {

            $file_count = count($element['name']);
            $file_arr_keys = array_keys($element);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++) {
                if(!$element[name][$i]){
                    next;
                }
                foreach ($file_arr_keys as $key) {
                    $files[$i][$key] = $element[$key][$i];
                }
            }

        } else {
            $file = $element;
        }
    }

    if (isset($file)) return $file;
    return $files;

}
```